# Running a program as a user without user permission?

Tags: permissions, sudo

There is a program that I am afraid to run under root (it may contain vulnerabilities), and I do not want to set the user execution permission, so that the functionality could not be used, for example, some other program.

The first thing that comes to mind is to run under root *(program root:user)*:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
chmod 750 program && su - user -c program; chmod 700 program
```

The second thought is to create a user just for this program, but I haven't yet encountered setting permissions so that the new user has permission for only one program, and access to everything else is denied. Also, if the program will be with GUI there may be problems with X11 access.

I want to run the program as an unprivileged *(regular)* user, but I do NOT want this program to be able to be run by any other process or anyone else (root, of course, does not count).

---

For example, there is a program that makes a screenshot, how to make so that only I can use it, but not a virus that got from the browser?

> This makes no sense.. If that browser virus would be able to execute
> processes, it would have all that it needs to either just download a
> program of the same functionality, or implement the functionality
> itself;

The first thing that comes to mind is what if we are talking about programs with a suid bit installed, to install which I need root access. This means that a virus which got in through the browser, but could not get root access, would be able to use this program. If the program would not have been allowed to be executed from user account, the virus would not have started it and without root access it would not have been able to install it, i.e. to use it.

---

Or a program simulating keystrokes, so that only I can run it (via wrapper or password or sudo as root or something else), but not a virus or another program/process.

Comment: Can it not just be run as normal by unprivileged users? I'm not sure what you're asking here as there isn't actually a question

Comment: Just make the program as owned by you and set the group & everyone permissions switched off. You will need to be signed on as you to run this "vulnerable" program. If you want other people to run your program, but with your user permissions, you could investigate the matter of SUID permissions - but only if this is some **absolutely vital component** of your installation. It's generally a really bad idea.

Comment: I, also, am not clear on what you’re asking. (1) Reading between the lines, I ***guess*** that you’re thinking “The (executable) file is currently protected 700 (and owned by root), so no user other than root can run it. So `su - user -c program` won’t work. But I’m reluctant to chmod it to 750, because this is a truly multi-user system (i.e., other *people* are using it concurrently) and I don’t want to let any of them run the program while I have it unprotected.” … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (2) Alternatively, you seem to be thinking that, ***in addition to this mystery program*** (let’s call it “program1”), you might have some *other* malware (let’s call it “program2”) already running on your system (but not [yet] running as root).  And you’re afraid that the two programs are working together, and that “program2” is waiting for an opportunity to run “program1”, so you want to keep “program1” bottled up.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (3) You say “create a user just for this program, but … setting permissions so that the new user has permission for only one program”.  This makes it sound like you want to run the mystery program in a straitjacket, so it can’t do any damage.  But then how will you know what it *tried to do,* unless it tells you? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete (i.e., explain your objectives and constraints).

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to do anything special to the program: root can run programs as any user they want using e.g. su or sudo, as you demonstrate. But then that user needs to execute thee program. Hence, what you want is impossible, making a program be executed by another user, but not allowing that user to execute thee program.

Your whole "change the permissions, run, change back" seems futile as well, because that target user (or specifically, the program it self) could make a copy while it's running. Or even just fork off into the background, happily exit and don't care about the file permissions, as it's already running in the background.

It's common at least on Linux systems to have a user "nobody" which basically has no privileges but is used to run daemons that should not be able to do much. Having multiple users of that kind is possible, but probably indicative of you really needing to thinthink what you want to secure against what, because:

> There is a program that I am afraid to run under root (it may contain vulnerabilities), and I do not want to set the user execution permission, so that the functionality could not be used, for example, some other program

Makes very little sense. Your other programs could have the same security issues, or they n could build the same program. Hell, with the ability to start anything and a halfway normal shell installed, you should be able to build a complete remote shell service on your machine.

This is a bit akin to saying

> I don't want to allow passengers to carry this brand of screws onto our flights, there's been quality control issues with the screws, and who knows what happens when they start replacing the screws in the airplane with this crap!

The problem is not the passenger's access to the bad screw, it's that you would allow them to take a screwdriver to the wings.

You're trying to secure the wrong end here. A user, by (not necessarily great) conception of Unix privileges, can always lay havoc or publish their own files. You can't protect them from that if they can execute arbitrary software.

What you can protect the system from is a user doing damage beyond their own scope. But that's not a question of stopping them from running an executable (which could only do that the user could do anyways), but stopping things running as that user to do damage.. That is what file permissions are for, what SELinux helps doing, and so on.

> Also, if the program will be with GUI there may be problems with X11 access.

Giving an X11 client access to your X11 server is basically game over. They can synthesize any key presses, eg. open up a terminal and type rm -rf /.

---

So, it's really not quite clear what the security boundaries you had in mind were.

---

> For example, there is a program that makes a screenshot, how to make so that only I can use it, but not a virus that got from the browser?

This makes no sense.. If that browser virus would be able to execute processes, it would have all that it needs to either just download a program of the same functionality, or implement the functionality itself; both are relatively common things to do in malware. Again, prohibiting a *specific* executable does **nothing** to secure your system.

Comment: I replied to you in my message